# How to perform dummy multi-inserts with generate_series()?

Tags: postgresql, cte, bulk-insert, postgresql-13

Given the tables like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/Z8hOhnYG

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE profiles (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE account_profiles (
  id bigint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  account_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES accounts,
  profile_id bigint NOT NULL REFERENCES profiles
);
```

The requirements are:

- every account must always have at least one profile tied to it.
- therefore a new account must always create a new profile and add their relation row to the database
- nothing is created when the entire operation fails for any reason.

So for the purpose of batching I'd like to write it as a multi-insert query and so I came up with this algorithm:

1. create a series of IDs with the same length as the number of accounts
2. add accounts
3. join new accounts with the series
4. add profiles
5. join new profiles with the series
6. join account and profile series tables on their series id and insert the result into the relations table
7. return new accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> GENERATED ALWAYS

You're going have to do `insert`-`returning` or use `lastval()`

After some discussion we arrived on this:

```
WITH input_sequence AS (
  SELECT
    generate_series AS index_id
  FROM
    generate_series(1, 5)
),
new_accounts AS (
  INSERT INTO accounts
  SELECT
  FROM
    input_sequence
  RETURNING    *
),
input_accounts AS (
  SELECT
    row_number() over () as index,
    new_accounts.id
  FROM
    new_accounts
),
new_profiles AS (
  INSERT INTO profiles 
    SELECT 
    FROM 
      input_sequence
    RETURNING
    *
),
input_profiles AS (
  SELECT
    row_number() over () as index,
    new_profiles.id
  FROM
    new_profiles
),
new_account_profile_pairs AS ( 
  INSERT INTO account_profiles ( account_id, profile_id )
  SELECT
    input_accounts.id AS account_id,
    input_profiles.id AS profile_id
  FROM
    input_accounts,
    input_profiles
  WHERE 
    input_accounts.index = input_profiles.index
)
SELECT
  index, 
  id
FROM
  input_accounts
ORDER BY 
  id;
```

Here I'm using the window function `row_bnumber() over ()` to assign row numbers to each new inserted row giving a number that they can be joined on in the final result set.

Comment: Wait I ran the counts and it's not supposed to have 125 `account_profiles`, or 25 input_accounts/input_profiles: https://dbfiddle.uk/u4IMGftY . How do you do 1-to-1 join on the generated series when their row counts are equal? I assumed `CROSS JOIN` would do just that, but it seems to create all index variations of rows instead.

Comment: yeah you don't want a cross join,  perjhaps a regular join on a.id %5   = b.id%5

Comment: I've made a new query it's shorter, but it uses the number of results in 4 different places,

Comment: Well in this case it would work, but in the real code series IDs and primary keys will never match up, so there is no condition for inner join outside of "record index" if it's a thing.

Comment: you simplfied the example so far that it is hard to guess what features are actually needed , I have another query that is closer in structure to your original

Comment: Generate_series is a kind of magic in that it doesn't cross-join with itself,  but if you wrap it in a CTE that magic evaporates,  this is why there were 125 results.

Comment: my second query works if the sequences aren't perfectly aligned, it does however require sequences that are have a step of 1 (or coprime with the number of rows)

Comment: Yeah I simplified it so it could be reduced to a concrete question, which is how to map rows of given record to some sort of temporary "transaction" IDs (like an index in an array) before the insert. These IDs are not the primary keys but are required to perform the multi-insert consistently. Think how it gets complicated if instead of 1 profile per account there could be created 0-10 profiles along with the new account in the series of new accounts.

Comment: As per [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/dml-returning.html) the `RETURNING` clause returns the rows in the order of insertion, so if the `INSERT` statement initiated off series, the order of newly created items will be the same as the series and thus it's possible to have a mapping between the initializer data without primary key to the newly table rows.

Comment: I guess in case of serial IDs the `rank()` works just fine, since the serial IDs would sort in the same order as the input values.

Comment: I can't think of any alternative in the absense of some natural key to use to recover the original series. most SQL does not respect order at all.

Comment: Can you edit your answer so it would include only the last query? I will mark it as an answer then.

Comment: I found a better way than rank...  `row_number() over ()`